# 3-D graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I have three lists x, y, and z of same size that I want to plot on a graph. Here's my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, label = 'curve')
plt.show()
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Graph.py", line 36, in <module>
ax.plot(x, y, z, label = 'curve')
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1513, in plot
    lines = Axes.plot(self, xs, ys, *args[argsi:], **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4139, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 319, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 281, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError('third arg must be a format string')
ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

Comment: x, y, and z are same length lists of integers.

Comment: using your code with three lists is working for me so the issue lies somewhere in your lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not properly initializing the 3D Axis. Fist, make sure you've imported everything properly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

Then, try adding a subplot to your figure, instead of accessing the current axis:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

If that doesn't fix it, you'll need to provide more detail.